# Alfresco integration with Web Service

Tags: web-services, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

I'm trying to make a Web Service in JAVA that communicates with Alfresco. This Web Service is requested by Alfresco to give informations about a document that is on Alfresco. So, I make a request from Alfresco to Web Service from a specific document, and the Web Service returns the information about this document to display on Alfresco.

I read that I can use [Alfresco CMIS](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/cmis/cmis-article.pdf) or [Alfresco Web Services API](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Content_Management_Web_Services) to make the communication with web services and Alfresco. Is that right? What is the difference between them and which is better for my problem?

Another important question is, to make the authentication, I saw in the book Alfresco CMIS by Martin Bergljung that I have to put "username" and "password" in the code. But, I want to adapt to all users of Alfresco, there are safe ways of authentication instead of this, give the authentication from Alfresco to Web Service for example? I read the book and I don't find the solution yet.

Comment: Use CMIS or the REST APIs every time - the WS* code is very old and receiving no updates or enhancements

Comment: Ok thanks! With CMIS for example I can ensure the resolution of the problems that I spoke in the question? Another important question is, to make the authentication, I saw in the book Alfresco CMIS by Martin Bergljung that I have to put "username" and "password" in the code. But, I want to adapt to all users of Alfresco, there are safe ways of authentication instead of this, give the authentication from Alfresco to Web Service for example? I read the book and I don't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the biggest difference between them is that since Alfresco 5 the WebService API isn't available anymore.

So I would think too much and go with CMIS.

Comment: Ok thanks! So with CMIS I can ensure the resolution of the problems that I spoke in the question? Another important question is, to make the authentication, I saw in the book Alfresco CMIS by Martin Bergljung that I have to put "username" and "password" in the code. But, I want to adapt to all users of Alfresco, there are safe ways of authentication instead of this, give the authentication from Alfresco to Web Service for example? I read the book and I don't find the solution yet.

Comment: You can use the authentication ticket from Alfresco instead of the username/password every request.
Other way is to write your own authentication implementation in CMIS. So you can verify your authentication, like CAS or OpenSAML

Comment: You advise to use tickets? In a security vision? Thanks a lot!